# Javascript:How can I find the position of element in the multi-dimensional array

Tags: javascript, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have a multi array like this:

> var tree=["root",null,["es1",null,["es11",null,"info for es11","param for es11],["es12",null,"info for es12","param for es12]],["es2",null,["es21",null,"info for es21","param for es21],["es22",null,"info for es22","param for es22]]]

If i want search for "*es22*", how can i get the position like `tree[3][3][0]`?
I have tried like this:

```
function recursion(obj,strs){
if (found) return;
for(var j=0;j<obj.length;j++){
    c++;
    if (isArray(obj[j])&&!found) {
        recursion(obj[j],strs);
    } else {
        if (obj[j]==strs&&!found) {
            arr=obj;
            found=true;
            return;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Your array is wrong. There is missing quotes

Answer (score 1):

Whenever the item is found, return the `index`, and append all previous indexes before it:

```js
var tree=["root",null,["es1",null,["es11",null,"info for es11","param for es11"],["es12",null,"info for es12","param for es12"]],["es2",null,["es21",null,"info for es21","param for es21"],["es22",null,"info for es22","param for es22"]]];

function recursion(arr, str, indexes) {
  var result;

  for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    if (Array.isArray(arr[i])) {
      result = recursion(arr[i], str, indexes);
      
      if(result !== null) {
        return [i].concat(result);
      }
    } else if(arr[i] === str) {
      return i;
    }
  }
  
  return null;
}

console.log(recursion(tree, "es22", []));
```

Comment: Good one +1, perhaps consider an array instead of concatenating indexes.

Answer (score 1):

This is my attempt...

```js
var tree = [
    "root", 
    null, 
    ["es1", null, ["es11"], ["es12"]], 
    ["es2", null, ["es21"], ["es22"]]
];

const find = (subtree, item, path = []) => Array.isArray(subtree) 
    ? subtree.some((e, i) => (find(e, item, path) && path.unshift(i))) && path 
    : subtree === item;

console.log(find(tree, 'es22'));
```

**Description:**

A depth first search. If `subtree` is an array, then enumerate. For each element, run the depth first search on that subtree.

If `subtree` IS `item` return `true`. This will cause the stack to unwind. At each stack frame, if the subtree search was successful, add current array index to the front of `path`.

Pass `path` up the stack frame chain if `item` was found in the subtree.

When complete, if the element was found, `path` is returned containing indices to the element, otherwise false is returned.

**Pseudocode:**

```
def solution(subtree, item, path)
  if subtree is not an array
    return subtree is item
  else
    for each index, value in subtree
      var found = solution(value, item, path)
      if found
        add index to path
        return path
      end if
    end for
  end if
end def
```

Answer (score 0):

Hope it helps:

**The imeplemntation:**

```
function findPosition(search, neddle) {
    for (let i = 0; i < search.length; i++) {
        if (search[i] === neddle) {
            return [i];
        } else if (Array.isArray(search[i])) {
            const match = findPosition(search[i], neddle);
            if (match.length > 0) {
                return [i].concat(match);
            }
        }
    }
    return [];
}
```

**And the test:**

```
// findPosition TEST
const tree = [
    "root",
    null,
    [
        "es1",
        null,
        ["es11", null, "info for es11", "param for es11"],
        ["es12", null, "info for es12", "param for es12"]
    ],
    [
        "es2",
        null,
        ["es21", null, "info for es21", "param for es21"],
        ["es22", null, "info for es22", "param for es22"]
    ]
];


const expected = [3, 3, 0].join(',');
const actual = findPosition(tree, 'es22').join(',');

if (actual === expected) {
    console.log('pass');
} else {
    console.log('fail');
    console.log(actual, 'not equal to', expected)
}
```